# EE DB Class question

Tags: database, query, classes

I've got this code:

```
$res = $this->EE->db->where(array('EventCode' =>$r["eventcode"]))
       ->limit(1)
       ->get('exp_course_events');
$course_date = $res->row('FormalDate');
```

but when I try to `echo $course_date;`, all I get is `Array`

Isn't this how to use the DB class to return a single row and get it's field values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had it inside loop for another Query

The reason it was doing this is because it was a `foreach` from another call like this:

```
$results = $this->EE->db->get_where('exp_willis_rosters', array('status' => 'I'));
$registered = array();
if($results->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach($results->result_array() as $row) {
        // get the corresponding event for the user in the roster row
        $res = $this->EE->db->where(array('EventCode' =>$r["eventcode"]))
               ->limit(1)
               ->get('exp_course_events');
        $course_date = $res->row('FormalDate');
    }
}
```

I moved the code to another place that works.

Answer (score 0):

That is because that's what you're probably getting!

If you want to see what's going on, do this:

```
$res = $this->EE->db->where(array('EventCode' =>$r["eventcode"]))
                    ->limit(1)
                    ->get('exp_course_events');

$course_date = $res->row('FormalDate');

var_dump($course_date);
```

And update your answer with the output of that var_dump command.